# An internal server error has occurred. Error ID: 63354000-61927

Tags: error-messages

When I tried to delete a record from a related list of a custom object in lightning I am getting the below error.

> An internal server error has occurred Error ID: 63354000-61927 (763517420)

I am not able to reproduce it in other orgs. Can anybody help me with this ?

Answer (score 2):

**What you are looking at is what salesforce calls a** [GACK](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2015/02/gack.html): A gack is our blue screen of death, our frowny Mac icon, our “the number you have reached is no longer in service”, our “Jedediah has died of dysentery”. A gack is what happens when an error got thrown within our application and we didn’t catch it and handle it.
What this means is that it’s not your fault. It’s ours. That’s why we apologize in that message. Sorry!

This friendly message is the above-water portion of a huge iceberg of functionality. The numbers you see are part of an elaborate system for efficiently bringing these events to the attention of R&D.

> Its time to log a case with support when you encounter the gack !

Comment: Thank you so much. I will go ahead and raise a case.

Comment: @SubbaraoMuppaneni your'e welcome!

Comment: @SubbaraoMuppaneni You can sometimes get a hint if you open the Developer Console and check the logs after generating the error. It's usually related to a trigger, although there's other ways it could happen as well.

Comment: @sfdcfox, I ddn't see any errors from Developer Console logs.

Comment: @SubbaraoMuppaneni  Are the debug logs enabled?

Comment: @codeyinthecloud, yes, the debug logs were enabled.